# Can Golang work with just HTML, CSS and JS... no Front-End Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, go, frontend

Can I write an API with Golang and Use just HTML,CSS and JavaScript to render it on a browser?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Yes, I can't think of any language where that would not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.
You can include the static directory (HTML,CSS,JS) in you Go web application and in your API endpoints

Take a look to the official documentation for the package net/http - https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/

You can see http.Dir() function and how it works